# mod_rewrite not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2&tree_page=$3 [L]
```

But it doesn't 100% work.

My goal is to do this:

```
index.php?page=users&id=10 -> /users/10
index.php?page=abc -> /abc
index.php?page=abc&sub_page=def -> /abc/def
index.php?page=abc&sub_page=def&tree_page=123 -> /abc/def/123
```

How can I achieve this with my mod_rewrite above?
The last /abc/def/123 is working, but the 3 above not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2&tree_page=$3 [L,QSA]
```